# Python Hashing Password using Function

Tags: function, python-3.x, hash, md5

I am trying to create a script that uses a function to ask a user for a password, and then prints both the plain text password, and the hashed password. I'm using the md5 hash, and believe I have the correct code to do so, I just can't figure out the correct placement for each line of code in order to call the function into use.

```
import hashlib

def makemd5(key_string):

    new_key_string = key_string.encode('utf-8')

    return (hashlib.md5 ( new_key_string ).hexdigest())

def main():

    password = str(input("Enter Password: ")) 

    print(password)

    print(makemd5)


main ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a function, use the function call syntax:

```
def func(arg1):
    return arg+1

arg = 5
result = func(arg)
print(result) #output: 6
```

So in your case:

```
password = str(input("Enter Password: ")) 
print(password)
hash = makemd5(password)
print(hash)
```